# Touch is not setting seconds in file creation

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've looked in documentation. It says, I can set the time creation this way:

```
touch -t 20000131151511 teste
```

I want to create a file with date of 2000/01/31 and 11:51:11.

But when I run that command it says invalid date format.

When I run without two final digits the command works but obviously don't set the seconds. Am I forgetting something? Is there another way to change creation date of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the ".":

```
-t STAMP
          use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time
```

---

```
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ touch -t 200001311151.11 teste
rinzwind@discworld:~/test$ stat /home/rinzwind/test/teste
  File: ‘/home/rinzwind/test/teste’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 815h/2069d  Inode: 1308353     Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/rinzwind)   Gid: ( 1000/rinzwind)
Access: 2000-01-31 11:51:11.000000000 +0100
Modify: 2000-01-31 11:51:11.000000000 +0100
Change: 2015-02-28 21:56:48.514848834 +0100
 Birth: -
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is **another** way to set the **creation date** of a file:

`touch -d 01/31/2000 teste`

Comment: what about hours?

Comment: See Rinzwind answer